# using regex to pull out mul words and strings

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am trying to pull out parts of a URL so that I can have them as separate dimensions within tableau. I would use contains but there would be to many parts to pull apart. Here is an example of a URL I am trying to pull apart.

The pattern of this url is on all of the urls for other affiliates

```
https%3A//mywebsite.com/5-in- 788788.html%3Fgoogleevent%3D49a78449hdvpi4444%26utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm
```

_campaign%3D5jifni4f%26utm_content%3D10037uri4rhri%26utm_term%3Dhttps

```
Dimension    Data within dimension
utm_source = google
utm_medium = affiliate
utm_campaign = 5jifni4f
utm_content = 10037uri4rhri
```

Answer (score -1):

Using named capture groups, this could work?

```
(%26(?<key>[\w]+)%3D(?<value>[\w\d]+))
```

Although I don't think regex is ideal for this. Look into `urllib` (specifically `unquote` to convert the hex characters, and `parse_qs` to convert to a `dict`)

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: See the edited answer. You should be able to use both of those functions to first clean the url, and then pull out the query key, value pairs that you need.